# d3.v3 bug when working with sortable tables?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an example D3 Javascript code (located at [here](http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/6366020)) that creates tables, which mix text, links, and bar charts... using the D3.js library.

The Gist example works fine, in both Chrome and Safari, using the d3.v2.js version that is accessible via the path:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?2.4.5"></script>
```

You can access the d3.v2.js source by following the path: "http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js" (which appears to tell me that I'm pointing to version "d3.v2.js").

IMPORTANT: In this case, I know the code is working fine because the column of "Nodes" are all HTML hyperlinks that are "drillable."  The problem(s) seem to start when I try to use d3.v3...

**NOTE:** I downloaded d3.v3 and, using a local copy of the sortable table example (which readers can get from: http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/6366020).  I pointed to the both versions of the d3.v3.js library (normal and minified) and get two different problems...

---

**PROBLEM #1:**
In the first case, I copied the un-minified file "d3.v3.js" to a local copy of "d3.js" and accessed it with the command:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../LIBS/D3/d3.js"></script>
```

When I do this, I get an error in the d3.js file that reads "**[Error] SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u8364' (d3.js, line 1175)**"  Also, in this case, the column of Nodes does not turn into a hyperlink (i.e. the full path of the link gets rendered as text, rather than a hyperlink).  (*This is consistent in, both, Chrome and Safari.*)

---

**PROBLEM #2:**
In the second case, I copied the minified file "d3.v3/d3.v3.min.js" to a local copy of d3.js and accessed it using the same path, above.  In this second case, I get no error but the Nodes in the first column still do not turn into hyperlinks (i.e. the full path of the link gets rendered as text, rather than a hyperlink).  (*This is consistent in, both, Chrome and Safari.*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

D3 in version 3 uses unicode characters in some of the code as variables names (in particular Greek letters in the projection code). When including the script, you need specify the character encoding, i.e.

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Note the `charset="utf-8"`.

Comment: Hi, This seems to get rid of the error message, when using the inflated/un-minified version.  However, it does not appear to solve the issue of the Nodes being rendered as HTML links.

Comment: It appears that the difference is that you now must render the HTML through an HTTP server in order for it to appear as a link.  This used to not be the case.  So, technically, this part is not broken but does require an HTTP Server, going forward (just like you need an HTTP server to read .CSV via D3, properly.